# Get nearest value that is out of datetime range if there is only one record in group

Tags: python, pandas

Have such dataframe:

[image]

I need first to filter data by *date_op* and then group by *key* column:

[image]

As you can there are two records for *key2* and one for *key1*. Right here a problem - I need not less than two records in a group. If there is only one record in group I would like to get the nearest record that is out of *date_op* bounds. These records are under index 3 and 5:

[image]

For this case this out-of-bound record is row with index 3. That means that expected result looks like this (despite the fact that it is less than filter datetime above):

[image]

Could you say please how can I reach this?

DataFrame:

```
data = [
 {'date_op': '2020-07-15 00:03:00', 'key': 'key1', 'value': 10},
 {'date_op': '2020-07-15 00:02:00', 'key': 'key2', 'value': 9},
 {'date_op': '2020-07-15 00:01:00', 'key': 'key2', 'value': 7},
 {'date_op': '2020-07-14 23:59:00', 'key': 'key1', 'value': 6},
 {'date_op': '2020-07-14 23:59:00', 'key': 'key3', 'value': 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Plase try to clarify the question, right now I am not able to understand what you are asking. Do you need to select the closer for every key to the time you have filtered in case there are duplicates? What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, @Let'stry. Did it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following can help you:

```
data["Appearance"] = data.groupby("key").cumcount()
df2 = data[(data["date_op"]>'2020-07-15 00:01:00')].copy()
df2["filter"] = int(1)
df3 = pd.merge(data,df2[["key","filter"]],on="key", how = "left")
df3[(df3["date_op"]>"2020-07-15 00:00:00") | ((df3["filter"] == 1) & (df3["Appearance"] <= 1))][["date_op","key","value"]]

    date_op             key     value
0   2020-07-15 00:03:00 key1    10
1   2020-07-15 00:02:00 key2    9
2   2020-07-15 00:01:00 key2    7
3   2020-07-14 23:59:00 key1    6
```

We just mark which keys appear in the filter with the `pd.merge` and then filter those taking into account to pick no more than two rows for each key.